# elements inside child components in Angular?

Tags: angular

For instance if I had

```
<app-component>

  <posts-component>

      <h1 class="title">Lorem</h1>

  </posts-component>

</app-component>
```

**There is some Angular API to query for that `h1` inside `<posts-component>` from AppComponent?**

Comment: Better to not use browser/document based selectors. Your question is a bit contrived because it depends a bit on what your posts-component looks like internally. Without actual code the only valid answer would be: yes of course this can be done using Angular API’s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Angular [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#elementref) class to achieve this. here is an example below:

your html goes like this -

```
  <posts-component>

      <h1 #myDOMElement class="title">Lorem</h1> *// added ref element as "myDOMElement"*

  </posts-component>

</app-component>
```

Inside your component.ts file -

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = "Angular ElementRef and @ViewChild Example";

  @ViewChild('myDOMElement', { static: true }) MyDOMElement: ElementRef;


  // If { static: true }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.MyDOMElement);
    this.MyDOMElement.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I am changed by ElementRef & ViewChild";
  }

  // if { static: false }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.MyDOMElement);
    this.MyDOMElement.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I am changed by ElementRef & ViewChild";
  }

}
```

Before Angular 8 we needed to get ElemementRef in the ngAfterViewInit() component lifecycle hook. But now we can set static to true and get element reference in the ngOnInit() component hook.

In version 9 you can remove the static property and use it in the ngAfterViewInit()